# Android Mysql Connection Error

Tags: android, android-networking, androidhttpclient

Hey Guys I'm trying to make registration page using mysqli and php for backend and java for front end. My PHP Connection file works file even i've inserted data as well when i tried to insert data using android application it doesn't insert and even it doesn't show any error in log.

I'm Begginer in android. Please forgive if you found any error.

Here is my Insert File

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');


$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$registration_num = $_POST['registration_num'];
$contact_num = $_POST['contact_num'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO tblregistration (Email, Password,Full_name,Registration_number,Contact_number)  VALUES ($email,$password,$full_name,$registration_num,$contact_num)";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "Successful";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Here is my Registration Page

```
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            str_email = "a";
            str_password = "a";
            str_full_name = "a";
            str_registration_num = "a";
            str_contact_number = "a";
            new InsertData().execute();
        }
    });

private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String JSON_STRING;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        JSONParser rh = new JSONParser();

        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

        data.put("email", str_email);
        data.put("password", str_password);
        data.put("full_name", str_full_name);
        data.put("registration_num", str_registration_num);
        data.put("contact_num", str_contact_number);

        JSON_STRING = rh.sendPostRequest(AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, data);

        return JSON_STRING;
    }
}
```

Here is my HttpURLConnection file

```
 public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    //Creating a URL
    URL url;

    //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //Initializing Url
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        //Creating an httmlurl connection
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //Configuring connection properties
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //Creating an output stream
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        //Writing parameters to the request
        //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;
            //Reading server response
            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(response);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your application?

Comment: Yeah I have  done it

Comment: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe). It show me this error while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Use proper JSON Format...!!!